# Binary to decimal converter function gives wrong solution

Tags: java, binary

Like the title says, I've made a small function that takes from the user string of ones and zeros and the output should be its decimal number but for some reason I get wrong answers, hope you'll help me find the problem.

```
public class ToDecimal{
public static void main(String[] args){

    String string = args[0];

    int length = string.length();
    int power = length - 1;
    int decimal = 0;

    while(length > 0){

        if (string.charAt(length - 1) == '1'){
            decimal = decimal + (int)(Math.pow(2, length - 1));
        } else if (string.charAt(length - 1) == '0'){

        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong string spelling...");
        }

        length--;
    }

    System.out.println(decimal);

}
```

}

Comment: The simplest way to do this would be `decimal = Integer.parseInt(string, 2);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are applying the exponents in a backwards order.  That is, on the first loop, you look at the last character, but apply the biggest exponent, `length - 1`, and the first character gets exponent `0`.

Use `power` as the exponent instead of `length - 1`, and increment `power` at the end of the `while` loop.

```
    decimal = decimal + (int)(Math.pow(2, power));
```

and

```
    length--;
    power++;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, adding to the power is wrong because we are going from big power to the smallest that is 2^0

Comment: It worked for me.  With your code, "1011" is _interpreted_ as "1101" and becomes `13`.  With my fix, "1011" is now correct -- `11`.  You want that last character, which is processed first in your loop, to have the lower power, 0.

Comment: but why do I need to increment the power variable every loop if the function reads my binary code from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

just reversed the string in the beginning and added the condition to decrement power.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String string = new StringBuilder(args[0]).reverse().toString();
    int length = string.length();
    int power = length - 1;
    int decimal = 0;

    while(length > 0){

        if (string.charAt(length - 1) == '1'){
            decimal = decimal + (int)(Math.pow(2, length - 1));
        } else if (string.charAt(length - 1) == '0'){

        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong string spelling...");
        }

        power--;
        length--;
    }

    System.out.println(decimal);

}
}
```

**Without reverse**

```
String string = args[0];
            int length = string.length();
            int power = length - 1;
            int decimal = 0;
            int i=0;
            while(i<length){

                if (string.charAt(i) == '1'){
                    decimal = decimal + (int)(Math.pow(2, length - i-1));
                } 
                i++;

            }


            System.out.println(decimal);
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the reverse method, how can I fix my code without it?

Comment: try to walk through what's happening here.